# How can I test for a SK physics contact within a SKNode subclass?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, physics

I have a subclass of SKNode called `Cell`. I set up all the physics bodies and they collide properly. However, the `didBeginContact()` function is in `GameScene` and I need it to be in `Cell` because I want to call a function declared in cell that alters the cells properties. Is there a way to set the delegate to an SKNode subclass? Or can I workaround and call the function within Cell from GameScene?

set up bit mask:

```
let cellCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
let foodCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
let borderCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
```

inside Cell, setup the physics body:

```
let physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 5)
self.physicsBody = physicsBody
self.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
self.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false
self.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = cellCategory
self.name = "cell"
self.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = cellCategory | borderCategory
```

also note: I am using Swift 3.0

EDIT: The answer below is correct. Heads-up to everyone:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    ...
}
```

has been renamed to

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    ...
}
```

as of Swift 3.0

Comment: Sharing code might help !

Comment: Sorry. I don't actually have access to my computer right now. I think this covers all the necessary details, but if the below solution doesn't fix it, I can share my code tomorrow @dip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your `didBeginContact` where it is (or at least don't move it to Cell). What you want is to cast to the node to your class `Cell`, the gist of it would something like this:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    if let cell = contact.bodyA.node as? Cell {
        cell.someFunctionThatBelongsToThisClass()        
    } else if let cell = contact.bodyB as? Cell {
        cell.someFunctionThatBelongsToThisClass()        
    }
...
```

The above will be rather messy and should be refactored for sure, but it should help you to get on the way....

Somewhat cleaner perhaps:

```
let cell: Cell? = contactBodyA.node as? Cell ?? contactBodyB.node as? Cell
cell?.someFunction()
```

Comment: I will try it in the morning. What do you mean by "messy"?

Comment: Just that it doesn't _look_ particularly nice.

Comment: Okay. I can bear with that, as long as it effectively accomplishes the task. Thanks.

Comment: Yes it should work fine. I just know that those `didBeginContact` functions have a tendency to become a bit unwieldy. But, I don't know what the rest of your app looks like anyway. ;-)

Comment: Okay. I'd like to verify your answer, but I can't check because didBeginContact is never called. I set the delegate and everything...

Comment: An educated guess would be that the category- and contact-bitmasks aren't set up properly, but I'm not able to do much besides guessing without access to any code...

Comment: Okay, I added the code to the question. Things bounce off each other properly, so I think the physics body is set up okay, but let me know if i did something wrong. thanks.